# use jquery in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova

Hi i am starting to use phonegap and i have some problems for make a button click action.

My best chance was:

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="botonPrueba">pulsame</button>
        <div id="mostrar"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources//jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
function muestraAction() {
    $("#mostrar").html("ola");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // jQuery is properly loaded at this point
    // so proceed to bind the Cordova's deviceready event
    $(document).bind("deviceready", function () {

        $("#botonPrueba").bind('click', muestraAction());

    });
});
```

In a normal webpage all work fine but in phonegap not.

where i wrong?

in browser say me that don't find cordova.js but in the emulator not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason you get the cordova.js issue in the browser is because it gets injected when you build the app. No problem there.

Your code is a little bit weird though, I would suggest this;

```
function muestraAction() {
    $("#mostrar").html("ola");
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

$(document).ready(function () {

    function onDeviceReady() {

        $("#botonPrueba").on('click', function () {
          muestraAction();
        )};

        // or even better if using jQuery mobile

        $("#botonPrueba").on('vclick', function () {
          muestraAction();
        )};

    });
});
```